# how to get impressions and engagements from Facebook by restFb API?

Tags: java, restfb

Is there anyway I can get impressions and enganements of any page on facebook from resrFB API.

Comment: We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `/insights` endpoint (they call it `edge`) of Graph API to get the data, [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/insights) is the documentation.

For impressions, your metrics would be `page_impressions_unique`, `page_impressions_paid_unique` and `page_impressions_organic_unique`.

For Engagaments, your metrics would be `page_engaged_users` and `page_post_engagements`.

You will need an access token to use the Graph API. [Here's](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api) some more documentation on general usage.

Comment: Thanks Darshan, I have tried that but not getting any impressions. I have tried in both way from FB Graph api and also restFB. only likes are coming here is the code FETCHING INSIGHTS at [restFB](http://restfb.com/documentation/)

Comment: You need to check your access token in FB's access token debugger tool and make sure you have `manage_pages` access to that page. Otherwise FB won't return anything.